# An expression of a conditional expectation using the law of iterated expectation

Tags: conditional-probability, conditional-expectation

Suppose that we have a discrete random variable $D$ with the support $\mathcal{S}_0=\left\{ d_1,\ldots,d_{20}\right\}$.

In addition, consider a subset of the support like $\mathcal{S}_1=\left\{d_1,\ldots,d_{10}\right\} \subset \mathcal{S}_0$.

Lastly, we have two continuous random variables $X$ and $Y$.

Here, I have two questions.

First, I want to express $\mathbb{E}\left[Y\middle|X,D=d_1\;or\;D=d_2\;or\;\ldots\;or\;D=d_{10}\right]$ as $\mathbb{E}\left[Y\middle|X,D\in \mathcal{S}_1\right]$.

Is this a valid expression? More compactly, is it possible to write
\begin{align*}
\mathbb{E}\left[Y\middle|X,D=d_1\;or\;D=d_2\;or\;\ldots\;or\;D=d_{10}\right]=\mathbb{E}\left[Y\middle|X,D\in \mathcal{S}_1\right]
\end{align*}.

Second, if the answer to the first question is yes, by the law of iterated expectation, the following derivation may be correct.
\begin{align*}
\mathbb{E}\left[Y\middle|X,D\in \mathcal{S}_1\right]&=\mathbb{E}\left[\mathbb{E}\left[Y\middle| X,D\in\mathcal{S}_1,D\right]\middle|X,D\in\mathcal{S}_1\right] \\[5pt]
&=\sum_{d\in\mathcal{S}_1}\mathbb{E}\left[Y\middle|X,D\in\mathcal{S}_1,D=d\right]\Pr\left[D=d\middle|X,D\in\mathcal{S}_1\right] \\[5pt]
&=\sum_{d\in\mathcal{S}_1}\mathbb{E}\left[Y\middle|X,D=d\right]\Pr\left[D=d\middle|X,D\in\mathcal{S}_1\right]
\end{align*}
Are any of the above statements incorrect?

In my shallow knowledge, the there is nothing wrong. But, I want to confirm my derivation.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's correct, but faster:
$$\mathbb{E}\left[Y\middle|X,D\in \mathcal{S}_1\right]=\frac{1}{Pr(D\in S_1|X)}\int\limits_{D\in S_1}YdP_{\Omega/X}=\frac{\sum_{d\in S_1}\mathbb{E}[Y.I_{\{d\}}(D)|X]}{\sum_{d\in S_1}Pr[D=d|X]}$$

Comment: Your suggestion is so compact. Thank you for answering my question.